# JS: Target and remove dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assume this is a common problem, but I haven't been able to find the answer in other threads.

The basic idea / goal here is that if a task is marked as important, it gets added to quadrant1. If it isn't, it gets added to quadrant2. When tasks are completed, they can be closed out by clicking on them.

**HTML:**
I have a simple page with:

- A text input (i.e. "task")
- Checkbox (i.e. "important")
- Submit button (i.e. "submitTask")
- Two divs ("quadrant1" and "quadrant2").

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#submitTask').on("click", function() {
    var task = $("#task").val();
    var important = $("#important").prop("checked");

    var addToQuadrant = function (task, important) {
      if (important == true) {
        $("#quadrant1").append(
          "<p class='taskHolder'> " + task + " </p>");
      } else if (important == false) {
        $("#quadrant2").append(
          "<p class='taskHolder'> " + task + " </p>");
      }
    });
  });

  addToQuadrant(task, important);

  $('body').on('click', '.taskHolder', function () {
    $('.taskHolder').slideUp();
  });
});
```

My problem is that since I use the same id (i.e. "taskHolder") for both paragraph elements, if I add more than one task to my page at a time, I can't remove more than one of them.

**My question is:** how can I dynamically add an element to the DOM while also giving it a unique id or selector so every task can be uniquely targeted and closed out?

Comment: *"since I use the same id"* - Never do this. By definition id should be unique. But if you want a click to hide/remove the clicked item you don't need ids at all, you can use a common class and then use `this` within the event handler...

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry, I wrote this example in a hurry. I don't actually use the same id, but I do use the same class and have the same problem.

Where do I add 'this'?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual class you are using. Also, the indenting is a little weird in your JS: it looks like you've missed the closing `}` from your `else if` and a closing `})` from the very end. Please check those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).slideUp();
```

instead of

```
$('.taskHolder').slideUp();
```

Within the event handler `this` references the element that the event applied to.

The following is the minimal code I'd use to implement your whole thing:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var task = $("#task");
  var cb = $("#important");
  
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("<p></p>", {
      text: task.val(),
      "class": "task"
    }).appendTo(cb[0].checked ? "#quadrant1" : "#quadrant2");
  });
  
  $("body").on("click", ".task", function() {
    $(this).slideUp(500, function(){ $(this).remove(); });
  });  
});
```

```css
div { border: thin black solid; margin: 4px; min-height: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Task: <input id="task"></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="important"> Important</label>
<button>Add</button>
<div id="quadrant1"></div>
<div id="quadrant2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the new ID for the each newly added element dynamically.

```
//New length every time you click
var newLength = $('[id^=taskHolder]').length + 1;
//Apply the new ID
$("#quadrant1").append(
     "<p id='taskHolder+newLength+'> New "  + newLength + " </p>");
```

```js
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    //New length every time you click
    var newLength = $('[id^=taskHolder]').length + 1;
    //Apply the new ID
    $("#quadrant1").append(
          "<p id='taskHolder+newLength+'> New "  + newLength + " </p>");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="quadrant1">
  <p id="taskHolder_1">New 1</p>  
</div>  
<button id="submitButton">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

User a global variable 'counter' and increase its value at each click then append this with 'taskHolder'. Now you have unique id for each task.

To select use startwith type selector.

```
var cnt = 0;
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#submitTask').on("click", function() {
    cnt++;
    var task = $("#task").val();
    var important = $("#important").prop("checked");

    var addToQuadrant = function (task, important) {
      if (important == true) {
        $("#quadrant1").append(
          "<p id='taskHolder" + cnt + "' > " + task + " </p>");
      } else if (important == false) {
        $("#quadrant2").append(
          "<p id='taskHolder" + cnt + "'> " + task + " </p>");
  };

  addToQuadrant(task, important);

  $('[id^=taskHolder]').on("click", function() {
     $(this).slideUp();
};

});
```

Alternative solution

A better solution could be common class to each of the tasks

```
 "<p class='commonClass" + cnt + "'> " + task + " </p>");
```

and

```
$('body').on('click', '.taskHolder', function () {
    $(this).slideUp();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use unique id
- Target item with $(this) to hide on complete.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  
      var addToQuadrant = function (task, important) {
       
          if (important == true) {
           var taskid = $("#quadrant1").length + 1;
            $("#quadrant1").append(
              "<p class='taskHolder' id='task-"+taskid+"'> " + task + " </p>");
          } else if (important == false) {
           var imptaskid = $("#quadrant2").length + 1;
            $("#quadrant2").append(
              "<p class='taskHolder' id='imp-task-"+imptaskid+"'> " + task + " </p>");
        };
         };  
  
      $('#submitTask').on("click", function() {

        var task = $("#task").val();
        var important = $("#important").prop("checked");
        addToQuadrant(task, important);
      });    


      $('body').on('click', '.taskHolder', function () {
        $( this ).slideUp();
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    Important Task
    <div id="quadrant1" style="border:1px dotted;min-height:20px;margin-bottom: 10px">
      
    </div>
    Task
    <div id="quadrant2" style="border:1px dotted;min-height:20px;margin-bottom: 10px">
    </div>


    Task: <input type="text" id="task" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="important" /> Important
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitTask" />
```